# [current-user:points) token showing points of the full category

Tags: drupal-7, token, drupal-modules, drupal-rules, userpoints

The token [current-user:points] showing points of the full category. Example, the token value displays the points of all articles in the article section and I had added the token in every article and now it showing the misleading information. Now, I want to show the points of current article ONLY and not the full article category. Experts, please help me to solve my problem. I will be thankful to you.